# Adding horizontal line below cell in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cashapelayer

I am implementing like a calendar layout with some modification which is shown in the screenshot. To achieve this I have used UICollectionView. The problem is, I have to draw a screen width continuous line(green line in screenshot). `The green line should cover the whole width`, I know its not showing over the circular cell due to `half of the cornerRadius` and a vertical line only after the first cell(10 am). Where i have to add the shapelayer, so that it ll seems like a continuous line. Here is the code which I have tried so far.

**KKViewController.m**

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KKBookCollectionViewCell

    self.bookingCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let rectangularRowIndex:NSInteger = indexPath.row % 5
    if(rectangularRowIndex == 0 )
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        cell.timeSlotLabel.text = "10am"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    }
    else
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.width/2
        cell.timeSlotLabel.text = ""
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor

        if cell.selected == true
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }

        else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

**KKCollectionCell.m**

```
var borderWidth:CGFloat!
var borderPath:UIBezierPath!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    drawHorizontalLine()
    dottedLine(with: borderPath, and: borderWidth)

    drawVerticalLine()
    dottedLine(with: borderPath, and: borderWidth)

func drawVerticalLine()
{
    borderPath = UIBezierPath()
    borderPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.size.width, self.frame.origin.y))
    //borderPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - 5, self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height - 50))

    borderPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.size.width, self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height))
    borderWidth = 2.0
    print("border path is %f, %f:\(borderPath)")
}

func drawHorizontalLine()
{
    borderPath = UIBezierPath()
    borderPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, self.frame.origin.y))
    borderPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + 10, self.frame.origin.y))
    borderWidth = 2.0
    print("border path is %f, %f:\(borderPath)")
}

func dottedLine (with path:UIBezierPath, and borderWidth:CGFloat)
{
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [1,2]
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

[image]

Comment: try with "bringsubViewToFront"

Comment: you mean like this `self.layer.bringSubviewToFront(self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer))`

Comment: Add a UIView to your cell and set the background and cornerRadius of the UIView rather than the cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new view inside the collection view cell and set the corner radius for that new view. Also you have to reduce the spacing between the cells. Then the line will look like what you expected.

Comment: Thats the problem, can't reduce the space between the cells

Comment: Have you reduced the minimumInteritemSpacing?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but it was never properly answered, i was looking for such behaivior and achieved it with the help of another answer.
To achieve that you need to subclass the UICollectionViewFlowLayout (maybe a simple layout also would do but i didn't try).

```
class HorizontalLineFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

var insets: CGFloat = 10.0
static let lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
    
    var attributesCopy: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    
    for attribute in attributes {
        attributesCopy += [attribute]
        
        let indexPath = attribute.indexPath
        
        if collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) == 0 { continue }
        
        let contains = attributes.contains { layoutAttribute in
            layoutAttribute.indexPath == indexPath && layoutAttribute.representedElementKind == HorizontalLineDecorationView.kind
        }
        
        if !contains {
            let horizontalAttribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: HorizontalLineDecorationView.kind, with: indexPath)
            
            let width = indexPath.item == collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 ?
                attribute.frame.width + insets :
                attribute.frame.width + insets * 1.5
            
            let frame = CGRect(x: attribute.frame.minX, y: attribute.frame.minY, width: width, height: 0.5)
            
            horizontalAttribute.frame = frame
            
            attributesCopy += [horizontalAttribute]
        }
    }
    
    return attributesCopy
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

the func layoutAttributesForElements is called each time, and it makes the lines for the cells you specify and for the frames you specify.

you would also need the decoration view which looks like that:

```
class HorizontalLineDecorationView: UICollectionReusableView {

static let kind = "HorizontalLineDecorationView"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    backgroundColor = .gray
    alpha = 0.2
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

in general its just a view that goes behind the cell, respectively to its indexPath, so the lines are not all along the screen but those are some lines gathered togather which look like a full line, you can adjust its width and height, play with that.

notice that frame that is set for an attribute in the layout, that is the frame of the decoration view, and is defined with respect to the cell (attribute).

dont forget to register that decoration view and also to make the layout and pass it to the collecitonview like this:

```
let layout = HorizontalLineFlowLayout()
    layout.register(HorizontalLineDecorationView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: HorizontalLineDecorationView.kind)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
    layout.sectionInset = .zero
    
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.register(DateCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "month")
    
    collectionView.delegate = monthDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = monthDelegate
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

the end result is [image]